# Magento 2 module - Product Comments

Tags: magento2, module

I need help creating module that allows to comment products. Module should add new attribute "allow commenting" with yes/no.

1. Products that are allowed for commenting should be displayed in a
   list.
2. When user opens product with enabled commenting, he sees product
   view with list of approved comments and a form to add new comment:
   name, e-mail, and text.
3. All comments are shown in the Magento backend, in separate menu tab
   under Vendor->Product Comments.
   In admin panel there should be default buttons, like edit, delete, save, back etc. So I am stuck at database.

First of all I created module ProductComments.

Then I created InstallData.php

```
    <?php


namespace Magebit\ProductComments\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'commenting',
            [
                'group' => 'General',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Allow Comments',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '1',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

And now I am thinking about the database, my idea is to create something like this, but will it be enough?

```
comment_id
product_id
date
email
name
comment - text
status - pending, approved, not approved
```